# the gradient of Busemann function

Tags: riemannian-geometry

For a Busemann function $b$ defined on complete non-compact Riemannian manifold, we know that $|\nabla b|= 1$. If the Busemann function has 2nd order derivative everywhere in weak sense, do we have $\nabla_{\nabla b}\nabla b= 0$ almost everywhere in weak sense?

Comment: For Hadamard manifolds, the Busemann function is always $C^2$ and for all $v$ you have $\nabla_v\nabla b=Y_v^\prime(0)$, where $Y_v$ is the Jacobi field (along the geodesic defining the Busemann function) with $Y_v(0)=v$. In particular, the vector you ask for is always zero. You may look at the proof in Section 3 of https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214434219 to check to which extent the proof of this generalizes to a more general setting than Hadamard manifolds.